# Como percorrer duas listas de tamanhos diferentes [PYTHON]?

Tags: python, loop, for, while

A ideia é a seguinte: Cada time tem 6 mapas jogados(mapList) fiz um web crawler que pega todas as informações referente ao time e ao mapa e queria inserir de forma automática em uma planilha usando o pandas. Porem me deparo com a seguinte situação... Ele sempre para na Fnatic que é o 6º time, por causa que só existem 6 mapas.

team = ["astralis", "navi", "big", "ence", "faze", "fnatic", "furia", "heroic", "liquid", "mibr", "mousesports","nip", "nrg", "renegades","vitality","g2","envy"]

mapList = ["mirage", "dust2", "inferno", "nuke", "overpass", "train"]

...

```
t = 0
while t < len(team):
     for m in mapList:
          TesteTime = Time(team[t], m, 0,0,0,0,0,0)
          TesteTime.leitura(team[t], m)
          TesteTime.handicapMedio()
          TesteTime.HandicapVitoria()
          TesteTime.HandicapDerrota()
          TesteTime.rounds()
     t+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matheus,

Para fazer isso você pode fazer como no exemplo abaixo:

```
team = ["astralis", "navi", "big", "ence", "faze", "fnatic", "furia", "heroic", "liquid", "mibr", "mousesports","nip", "nrg", "renegades","vitality","g2","envy"]
mapList = ["mirage", "dust2", "inferno", "nuke", "overpass", "train"]


for row_Team in team:
    for row_Map in mapList:
        print(row_Team + ' - ' + row_Map)
```

O for vai percorrer a lista de time, e a cada time vai percorrer cada mapa.

Comment: Em termos de percorrer a lista e printar as duas juntas realmente funcionou, porem ainda quebra quando se usa os metodos =\

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bd.py", line 87, in <module>
    a.atualizandoCSV()
  File "bd.py", line 62, in atualizandoCSV
    TesteTime.leitura(row_Team, row_Map)
  File "/home/costa/Desktop/trade_3.0/src/team.py", line 39, in leitura
    self.resposta3 = filtro.findall(linha[26])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Você fez algo como isso ?

for row_Team in team:
    for row_Map in mapList:
        print(row_Team + ' - ' + row_Map)
        TesteTime = Time(row_Team, row_Map, 0,0,0,0,0,0)
        TesteTime.leitura(row_Team, row_Map,)
        TesteTime.handicapMedio()
        TesteTime.HandicapVitoria()
        TesteTime.HandicapDerrota()
        TesteTime.rounds()

Comment: Sim, mas quando chega no sétimo time, ele para e da: list index out of range

Comment: Tenta passar da forma que eu mandei ai. Porque ele quebraria se passasse via index como não é acredito que não vai quebrar dessa vez.

Comment: Eu passei da forma que voce mandou, sem usar o index, a unica diferença é que o print(row_Team + ' - ' + row_Map) ta abaixo do .rounds()

Comment: Ta muito estranho porque fiz aqui e deu certo. Até dividi em dois arquivos.

Arquivo 1:

from teste import testTime

team = ["astralis", "navi", "big", "ence", "faze", "fnatic", "furia", "heroic", "liquid", "mibr", "mousesports","nip", "nrg", "renegades","vitality","g2","envy"]
mapList = ["mirage", "dust2", "inferno", "nuke", "overpass", "train"]

for row_Team in team:
    for row_Map in mapList:
        teste = testTime()

        TesteTime = teste.TesteTime(row_Team, row_Map)
        print(TesteTime)

Arquivo 2:

Comment: Arquivo 2:


class testTime:

    def TesteTime(self, time, mapa):
        retorno = time + '-' + mapa
        return retorno

Comment: Assim, o PRINT funciona corretamente, mas quando chega na execução dos metodos ele funciona perfeitamente. Ja testei até individualmente os metodos e todos funcionam, porem quando adiciono os metodos no for, ai ele quebra e da list index out of range

Comment: Pode ser que ao passar um time e um determinado mapa quebra dentro do método e não no for.

Comment: Justissimo, acabei de verificar meu programa pega as 10 ultimas partidas de cada mapa, quando chega na furia ela só tem 2 partidas em um mapa e quebra, obrigado por abrir meus olhos!!

Comment: Boa!  ....... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 for t in team:
    for m in mapList:
        TesteTime = Time(team[t], m, 0,0,0,0,0,0)
        TesteTime.leitura(team[t], m)
        TesteTime.handicapMedio()
        TesteTime.HandicapVitoria()
        TesteTime.HandicapDerrota()
        TesteTime.rounds()
```

Comment: mas o resultado desejado é:

astralis mirage
astralis dust2
astralis inferno
astralis nuke
astralis overpass
astralis train

E assim por diante, coisa que ele já faz, porem quando chega na furia ele já para e quebra o while

Comment: Editei a resposta.